# Upgrading my Wubi 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, 11.10, wubi

I want to upgrade my current Wubi installation (Ubuntu 11.04) to Ubuntu 11.10. Is this possible to do inside Wubi? Or do I have delete Wubi from Windows, therefore deleting my current Ubuntu installation; and then install 11.10 via the Wubi installer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade a Wubi install - the same way as a normal upgrade, either from the Update Manager or via the [Alternate CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD) (while running your Wubi Ubuntu). Note that the alternate CD has been discontinued since release 12.10 so you have to use the Update Manager.

I recommend that you check you have plenty of free space - at least 3GB - the upgrade underestimates the space it needs ([bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/986272)).

Also, a quick and easy precaution is to backup the `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` from Windows before upgrading - that way, if it fails you can just copy over the root.disk from before the upgrade.

Note that upgrading to `14.04` will require a [manual workaround in order to boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/453411/14916).

Comment: Will my Gnome desktop stay intact? I read that 11.10 doesn't have Gnome included by default, but can be added manually.

Comment: Probably not since I think Gnome went from 2 to 3. From what I've read you'll have to install the gnome-shell package and reconfigure it. I see there is also a gnome-panel that is similar to Gnome 2. I think this is probably a (good) separate question.

Comment: Here's some info on gnome-shell: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-10-guide/

Comment: Thanks! I actually decided not to upgrade, since 11.10 seems to have many issues right now. I'll just wait until it becomes more stable. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can upgrade when you boot to the wubi install. You can try Alt+F2 then type `update-manager -d` but I recommend reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGe

I also suggest dual booting, however, if you plan on long-term use. Wubi is for evaluation and is known to run into issues down the road.

Comment: Okay...yeah I know wubi is not recommended for long term use, but I'm planning on building a dedicated PC for Linux.

Comment: According to the wiki in my post, upgrade from Wubi wasn't supported since the 9.10 release; that wiki may be out of date.
Also, if my answer solved your issue, please accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went ahead and dual-booted 11.04 with Windows 7 by installing 11.04 on an external hard drive. I decided not to upgrade, since there seems to be many issues with 11.10 right now. I'll just wait until the bugs are worked out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the update, and it didn't work sadly. I have no way to revert back because I can't log in, and when I tried to uninstall wubi it failed in the middle. So I'd say wait till wubi has the option for 11.10.