# can I upgrade wubi from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading my Wubi 11.04 to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65740/upgrading-my-wubi-11-04-to-11-10)

I already have wubi installed with ubuntu 11.10, but want to upgrade it to 12.04 LTS. Do I need to remove wubi 1st ? Can I grow the partition that wubi uses ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly - but be careful.  Make sure before you try anything that everything is backed up and you have the means to re-install Windows if all else fails.  My advice woud be to download the 12.04 DVD and boot from it.  Use the 'Try Ubuntu' option and make sure everything works OK.  If it does, you have to consider whether you are ready to do a full installation, or whether you want to stay with wubi.  If you want to move from wubi that could be the better option.

Comment: Upgrading wubi won't affect windows. It might break ubuntu.

Comment: It shouldn't affect Windows, but it does update-grub and if this goes wrong it could affect the boot into Windows.  That's why I urge extreme caution.

Comment: Those grub problems have been fixed since 11.04 was released. And `update-grub` runs anytime a kernel is updated, so has nothing to do with release upgrades. There's always a theoretical possibility of problems, but in this case I'd say it's remote enough not to be a concern.