# Will I be able to upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 with a Wubi installation?

Tags: wubi, 13.04

Will it be possible to upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 on a wubi-enabled installation? I was looking at the schedule and noticed that Wubi is being discontinued.

I like the setup I have now (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10), and would like to use 13.4.

Comment: Wubi installations are not intended for prolonged use. If you come to a point of considering an upgrade, I'd recommend installing to a proper partition.

Comment: Yes. Refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/65740/upgrading-my-wubi-11-04-to-11-10

Answer (score -1):

Wubi instalations are not required but are working well. (You just notice that I/O disk performance is bad). 
With the support dropped, you cannot instal it. You can however try and upgrade from 12.10 after having verified that there were no changes in grub/kernel versions from 12.10 to 13.04.
My advice is to keep a 12.04 LTS w/ Wubi if you want to keep that configuration.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand the question, or at least you are not well informed..