# Upgrading from 12.10 WUBI install to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, wubi, 13.04

Ubuntu has discontinued wubi.exe and i know that when you install the ubuntu 13.04 developer version with wubi you can only login as a guest. I have previously installed ubuntu 12.10 with wubi.exe if i upgrade to 13.04 will everything work normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upgrade a Wubi install to 13.04, but Wubi support has been [officially pulled by Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes?action=show&redirect=RaringRingtail%2FTechnicalOverview#Ubuntu_downloader_for_Windows_discontinued), therefore it's not recommended to do this.

Confusingly though, the 13.04 `wubi.exe` (signed by Canonical UK Ltd.) has been published on http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04 (for undisclosed reasons). 
And no, the 13.04 wubi.exe doesn't only create a guest account. This bug was fixed.

If you do decide to upgrade which is generally not recommended on Wubi installs, then review this: [Upgrading my Wubi 11.04 to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65740/upgrading-my-wubi-11-04-to-11-10)
Also consider that you may not be able to get support from this site or other Ubuntu support sites.

Comment: Whether the bug is fixed or not, Wubi support was dropped from 13.04.  We can't provide support here for 13.04 Wubi software, nor can any other Ubuntu site.  The reason I said "No" is because you lose all your avenues of support by doing this.

Comment: @TheLordofTime yes that does seem to be a conundrum. Maybe it should go to meta.

Comment: No, this question is on topic here on main.  But I already [started a meta discussion on 13.04 Wubi questions and Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6504/how-do-we-handle-13-04-wubi-questions), and we already made clear that new 13.04 Wubi questions (relating to 13.04 Wubi support, not upgrading to 13.04 within Wubi which is pretty stupid to do anyways) are offtopic, or need to be duped to other questions that exist, and we already have a course of action.