# Upgrading Wubi installation

Tags: installation, upgrade, wubi

As Wubi is no longer supported I can obviously no longer use it to install the latest version of Ubuntu, so here's my question.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi and then update it to 13.04 in the Wubi installation? And if I can but it is risky to do so why is it risky and how can I protect my data.

Comment: If you want 13.04 get it from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/wubi.exe There's no point in upgrading a 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 and no reduced risk by doing so.

Comment: See [Updating to 13.04 failed in WUBI install of Ubuntu 12.10. What should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287871/updating-to-13-04-failed-in-wubi-install-of-ubuntu-12-10-what-should-i-do)