# I have problems installing Ubuntu 13.04 with Wubi on Windows XP

Tags: installation, wubi

I have downloaded an ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso file, but when I use Wubi to install it in a Windows XP system, the Ubuntu installer program shows: `download ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent`. It would take about two hours to download it. Why does this happen? It`s a lot of trouble for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi doesn't support Ubuntu 13.04. See also this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285418/upgrading-from-12-10-wubi-install-to-13-04). Ubuntu 12.10 is the last version that could directly be installed with Wubi.

You might want to install 12.10 and upgrade. Or just install 13.04 from a bootable DVD and install it on it's own partition.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not work with Ubuntu 13.04. Although you could just install 12.10 and upgrade, you would probably lose some stability. If you really want cutting edge features, but no risk, you may want to try installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Here's [a guide](http://www.dillonmorse.me/blog/posts/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-virtualbox/) on how to get it to work in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Wubi 13.04 where, if you computer supports 64 bit, it cannot find the 32 bit ISO. This is because recently they changed the 64 bit kernel name, and Wubi is looking for that kernel on the ISO and fails to find it.

To fix this, run Wubi with the `--32bit` command line option. Also, make sure you have the 13.04 Wubi.exe and save it in the same directory as the ISO before running (or if you have mounted the ISO, make sure you use the command option `--force-wubi` or the *Install inside windows* option is suppressed).

If you have issues, check the log file.