# When i open wubi.exe for installing edubuntu it again downloads the edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386 .iso file.Why does this happen?

Tags: 13.10, edubuntu

I downloaded the edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.iso file from bittorent and installed it on my pendrive using UUI. Then i went to the drive and opened wubi.exe, and i clicked on install.
The window showed that edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.iso was downloading. Why is it downloading again?

Comment: **Don't use WUBI.** Boot from the pendrive and select try Ubuntu without installing. Make sure everything works. Then click on the install icon.

Comment: @user68186 I disagree. Running it from a pendrive is a great way to test if things work. Installing it properly is great if you want to go all-in, including replacing the Microsoft boot loader with the Linux flavor. But the strength of Wubi is to retain the Microsoft boot loader and system, and put Linux in second rank.

Comment: 1. Wubi does not work with Windows 8 and above. 2. If the underlying  file-system gets corrupted (for example, for improper shutdown of either Windows or Ubuntu),  WUBI won't boot. 3. WUBI only allows for 30GB of virtual disks. So, IMHO it is a disaster waiting to happen the next time Windows crashes or files (including the WUBI virtual disk) are encrypted in Windows by the cryptolocker malware.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version in WUBI doesn't always work. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/285418/upgrading-from-12-10-wubi-install-to-13-04

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Are you trying to use WUBI on your pen drive, or on the HDD of your computer?
If the former, why? and if the latter then WUBI needs an iso file to install from, not a bootable pen drive.
You need to download the iso file and place it in the same directory as WUBI.exe. Then when you run WUBI it will find the iso file and install from that.