# Having problems with Grub prompt

Tags: grubrescue

Updated from 12.04 to 12.10.  Ubuntu won't startup.  Wouldn't reach login screen.  I booted Ubuntu from disc, and did boot repai, then restarted, and went to a terminal like thing with prompt "grub>". Please help.  Here's link http://paste.ubuntu.com/6707006/

Answer (score 0):

From the boot-repair log it was clearly shown that there was no sign of installed Ubuntu os on the HDD.

You may installed it through wubi.To upgrade a wubi install see [Upgrading from 12.10 WUBI install to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285418/upgrading-from-12-10-wubi-install-to-13-04) or [*this*](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-upgrade-wubi-install.html).

Comment: I can't do that.  I just have a black screen with the prompt grub>.    I used sub I to install.  What do I type into the command with prompt "grub>"

Comment: did you installed ubuntu through wubi?

Comment: If yes means see http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/202806.

Comment: Thanks for the help and all, but here's where I am.  Upgraded to 12.10.  I did boot fix from a disk. Now I restarted the computer.  It gives me grub prompt.  I just want to know what to type in.  I don't think that site will help.  Thank you for all the help though, much appreciated.