# Will I have problems updating to 13.04 when 12.10 was installed using WUBI?

Tags: wubi, 13.04

Basically, that's what I'm trying to figure out. How can I install the latest version WITHOUT using wndows?

Comment: This may or may not be the right answer for you, "http://askubuntu.com/questions/65740/upgrading-my-wubi-11-04-to-11-10" Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I got a pop-up asking me if I wished to upgrade to 13.04 an hour or so ago, I would think it would be the same way for everyone. (Well it was after I did a software update)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not have any problems with doing it that way with the update manager or you can Alternate use Dvd and set up partition and install it the normal way with out WUBI What I do and if you want to duel boot it it is easy from the GUI installer it should have a option to do that!